# Broadcom BLE SDK

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to run samples provided in [BroadCom BLE SDK](http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/). i have created AVD by installing this SDK but the application is not getting installed on the emulator. It gives as error which says

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
>   [2012-04-18 14:17:59 - BleFindMeServer] Please check logcat output for more details.
>   [2012-04-18 14:17:59 - BleFindMeServer] Launch canceled!

Any pointers to a solution to this? Do we have to run this sample on the actual device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing this thread.

http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/Bluetooth-Low-Energy-on-XT910/td-p/24412

The android device you are building on may not contain the shared library, in this case the broadcom ble sdk. So while your application may build, the device won't recognize the shared library as it does not support it.

If you want to test and use BLE on a device, you will have to make sure that device supports BLE. Currently, I think these are only Motorola devices, and you will have to include the Motorola designated BLE SDK for the particular device.

You can find more information here. http://developer.motorola.com/docs/bluetooth-low-energy-gatt-framework-api/

On another note, As far as i know, the android emulator does not support bluetooth. Classic or BLE.

Hope this helps

Comment: More ble devices are out or soon coming out, Samsung Galaxy SIII, and HTC EVO 4G LTE

Comment: as well as the HTC One X+, HTC Droid DNA