# Android Custom SDK issue with uses-library in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using a custom SDK downloaded from Broadcom to access the BLE chip on the phone. I downloaded and installed the SDK via the SDK manager and the documentation said to include this line in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.broadcom.bt.le" android:required="true" />
```

I created a AVD using the Broadcom SDK. When I try to debug using the emulator or the phone I get these errors:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/

Any thoughts?

Comment: You may not be able to use that with the emulator, unless they provide you with an emulator image customized to support it, or give you some means of installing an emulation of the library and hardware it talks to on an ordinary emulator.  As a guess though, they probably just don't support the emulator at all, since it likely would be hard to make it meaningful for the tasks one would do with that SDK.

Comment: Check this related post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206152/broadcom-ble-sdk

Answer (score 1):

[`<uses-library>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html) is used to specify that a shared library mentioned in this element is **required in the device** for this package to be installed. So the library has to be present in the device for the installation to proceed. And obviously whatever you are mentioning in this element is not present in the device causing the installation error.

Please try without specifying the element and report any errors.